# Facebook PHP SDK v.5 get pagination to work

Tags: php, facebook, pagination

I did a simple page following the tutorial here: https://github.com/sohaibilyas/facebook-php-sdk-v5/blob/master/get-all-photos-of-user.php

It works, I can get all of my pictures after login but I cannot get pagination to work. Where should I edit my code to get for example 25 picture per page?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From the code https://github.com/sohaibilyas/facebook-php-sdk-v5/blob/master/get-all-photos-of-user.php#L68 you can see there is a `/me/photos?limit=100&type=uploaded`

if you change 100 to 25, it will return at most 25 photos
if you wan to use pagination, you need to use the `offset` param. However it is not recommended by the doc, it suggest using the `Cursor-based Pagination`

you can find the detail doc for facebook photo api here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5#paging

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But if I change /me/photos?limit=100&type=uploaded to /me/photos?limit=25&type=uploaded it does not change at all, I receive all of my photos any way

Comment: @FrancescoMinoMatrioskaFogli I haven't used fb api before, butI think change the limit should work, do you have more than 25 photos returned? and here is a example for using fb sdk for pagination https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_pagination_basic/5.0.0

Comment: thank you again for answer! If I change from 100, to 25, or 1, or 4000 in the limit, I receive always all of my photos with some different order, but always each of them.....